# How do I configure the Pro Power Tools Extension for VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pro-power-tools

I find some of the features of the Pro Power Tools Extension to be annoying. Is there any way to turn features on and off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Pro Power Tools adds options into the standard options menu (Tools->Options) under the "Productivity Power Tools" section.  You can configure it there.